# Python Interpreter path does not work for me

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am doing the Tutorial of Django on YouTube, which can be found on the following URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHux0gMZ3Eg
After creating a virtual environment and starting a project in Virtual Studio Code, he tries to add the Python path into the VSCode.
In the video he is then able to use Python from the terminal inside the VSCode.

However, around minute 19 you can find that in the video. If I do it by myself, nothing is happening, and I am also not able to use Python on the VSCode then. I did not figure out, what I am doing wrong, since I am exactly doing it like in the video.
Does anyone have an idea, what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please describe in detail what you did, what happened, and what you expected to happen instead. Nobody is going to watch a video and then guess what you may have done or tried. Don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Comment: Hi Robert,

After creating the Virtual Environment with: „pipenv install Django“
And Starting it with „pipenv shell“, i am starting VScode with „Code .“

Then i get the path of Python with: 
„pipenv—venv“
After that i take the path and try to Add it in the vscode with the „Python interpreter“, But this step is not Working for me.

Comment: The Path i get with the command "pipenv --venv" is the following:

C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\storefront-XXXX\Scripts\python.exe

Then i take the path to add it in the vscode to use the integrated terminal in vscode. Therefore i open the "Command Palette" and search for "python interpreter" and then "enter interpreter path" and add the path from above. 

By pressing enter nothing happens then and this is why i am asking here to ask you, if anyone had the same issue or maybe knows, what i need to do to be able to use the intergrated terminal.

Comment: Can you run python on your computer?What happens if you type ```python``` on your command line? If you typing ```python``` on the command line doesn't open an interpreter, try reinstalling with ```add python to PATH``` checked

Comment: Do you mean the command line in vscode or the general cmd window? 
By typing "python" into the general cmd window, i receive the following: 

Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

By typing it into the vscode terminal i receie the same.
This is very strange, because my tests from the vscode terminal didnt work with "python manage.py runserver" and i just tried again and it seems to work now.

Comment: Actually i did not even change anything. The only difference is still, that i dont get the extra directory "vscode", which includes a file named "settings.json". in the tree structure. I dont know, if this is gonna be a problem for later steps in the project, but for now the terminal seems to work all of a sudden. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you added `C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\storefront-XXXX\Scripts\python.exe` in the Command palette you have switched the python interpreter. You can find it out from the bottom-right on the VSCode, looks like this:

[image]

But it will not work in the older terminal which opened before switching the python interpreter. You need to create a new terminal(shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+`). That's why after you restart it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes i can confirm, that in the bottom right there is now the path to the virtual env python.exe and not the venv anymore. :)) Thank alot for the help!

Maybe the directory, which appears in the tutorial video is due to the fact, that the creator is using a mac.